# How to use str_detect() to select rows and then create a new variable based on the pattern it is matched with?

Tags: r, stringr

I have a data set of a few hundred thousand rows. Below is an example of what they look like.

```
  X      user_id     screen_name                name        location
  1 1 1.732895e+09   DROPPSScience   DROPPS Consortium                
  2 2 1.172266e+18    Lamy40283167  Alex lamy precious Washington, USA
  3 3 3.773702e+08         cdockjr      Calvin Wilborn    Alabama, USA
  4 4 7.040063e+07           xmtl2             Felicio                
  5 5 3.929519e+08    DeleceWrites Delece Smith-Barrow  Washington, DC
  6 6 1.130459e+18    evabrooke_26                 Eva                
  7 7 1.067302e+08 MitchellHortert Mitchell R. Hortert   Pittsburgh,PA
```

I have a second data set found at https://github.com/jasonong/List-of-US-States/blob/master/states.csv

I am trying to use str_detect() to find any matches between the "location" column and either column in the states.csv file. I would then like to create a new variable that stores the matched pattern for each observation.

So far I have tried using

```
data.set %>%
    filter(str_detect(location, paste(states$State)
```

This returns some matches, but omits many observations and gives the warning

```
Warning message:
In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

states$State is a factor variable with 51 levels for each state and DC. 
What causes this warning, with very few matches but it works on some level?

Finally, how would I create a new variable that is based on when a match does occur, putting the matching pattern in the new variable?

Comment: Did you try using a mutate()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both the 'location' and 'State' are not of the same length, an option is to use `collapse` in `paste` to recognize each of the patterns.  It serves as `OR`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
data.set %>%
    filter(str_detect(location, paste(states$State, collapse = "|")))
```

As we are already using `stringr`, `str_c` can replace `paste`

```
data.set %>%
    filter(str_detect(location, str_c(states$State, collapse = "|")))
```

Or as @HanselPalencia mentioned, if there are confusion in 'State' use the `Abbreviation' column for pattern detection

```
data.set %>%
  filter(str_detect(location, str_c(states$Abbreviation, collapse = "|")))
```

Comment: It's to be noted that the state of Pittsburgh is Pennsylvania, so we always have to find a way to detect using abbreviations where it is necessary.

Comment: To get the match in a new variable you would use a mutate() instead of a filter saying something to the effect of `mutate(matches =str_detect(location, str_c(states$State, collapse = "|")))` (taken from @Akrun)

Comment: The mutate function worked, but the newly added variable is TRUE or FALSE based on if there was a match. Is there a method for pasting the pattern that caused the match in this new variable?

Comment: @Auresm If you need to extract the. pattern use `str_extract` i.e. `data.set %>% mutate(newcol = str_extract(location, str_c(states$Abbreviation, collapse = "|")))`